# Longest Suffix-Prefix Overlap Algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, bioinformatics, suffix-array, suffix

I have been tasked with identifying an efficient algorithm [O(n*log(n))] that, given a set of k Strings S = {s-1, s-2, s-3, ..., s-k}, will identify the longest substring T for each pair of strings (s-i, s-j), such that T is a suffix of s-i and a prefix of s-j, as well as the longest substring T for each pair of strings (s-j, s-i). n represents the added lengths of all k strings (n = |s-1| + |s-2| + |s-3| + ... + |s-k|).

Any thoughts? A link to a solution would be fine as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is vague. longest substring of suffix of `Si` and prefix of `Sj` is the whole of `Si + Sj`. Are we talking about longest  common/Uncommon substring?

Comment: What is the `n` in O(log n)? Did you mean `k`? The total number of characters in all the strings? Anyway, logarithmic time seems incredibly optimistic for an algorithm which produces k² result strings. Did you maybe mean O(n log n)? Please clarify.

Comment: @thebenman : The goal is for the longest substring which appears in String Si as a suffix AND String Sj as a prefix.

Comment: @rici : I did indeed mean O(n*log(n)) time. My apologies. N represents the added lengths of all k strings. I will edit the question to reflect these clarifications.

Comment: The common prefix/suffix seems like the sort of problem which yields to a suffix tree. It's easy enough to construct a trie of all the strings in linear time, which allows ordered traversal; the suffix tree can also be created in linear time.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a solution which relies on Suffix Arrays. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm 4.10 on page 61 of the book [Algorithmic Aspects of Bioinformatics](https://books.google.be/books?id=_DMvZC6zJqAC&pg=PA61&dq=bioinformatics%20longest%20common%20substring%20O(n*log(n))&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo2LW0kdzWAhWGYVAKHVW0AUkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=bioinformatics%20longest%20common%20substring%20O(n*log(n))&f=false) gives a method of computing the longest common substring of a set of given strings using suffix trees

[image: computing the longest common substring of a set of given strings using suffix trees]

The article also explains how finding the longest common substring is possible

> in linear time with respect to the size of the suffix tree, i.e. in *O(n log n)*.